# SQL Server Report Builder - Multiple Datasets in 1 Table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to create a report table that pulls in data from multiple datasets, Here are some of the datasets:

```
Database-Austin
Dataset-TexasList
+----------+
| Location |
+----------+
|Dallas    |
|Houston   |
|Austin    |
+----------+

Database-Austin
Dataset-AustinCount
+----------+------+
|Location  |Count |
+----------+------+
|Austin    |4056  |
+----------+------+

Database-Dallas
Dataset-DallasCount
+----------+------+
|Location  |Count |
+----------+------+
|Dallas    |51666 |
+----------+------+
```

Here is what I'm trying to get the final report to look like:

```
+----------+------+
| Location |Count |
+----------+------+
|Dallas    |51666 |
|Austin    |4056  |
+----------+------+
```

I've created a report table using TexasList as the source and `=LOOKUP(Fields!Location.value,Fields!Location.value,Fields!Count.value,"AustinCount")`      |

Which was successful in displaying:

```
+----------+------+
| Location |Count |
+----------+------+
|Dallas    |      |
|Houston   |      |
|Austin    |4056  |
+----------+------+
```

But I don't know how to get the other values in there.

I should mention that I cannot link the database servers together, otherwise I think I could make quick work of this.

Comment: I have not tested this but try this.. --> =LOOKUP(Fields!Location.value,Fields!Location.value
,switch(Fields!Location.value = "Austin",Fields!Count.value,"AustinCount",
Fields!Location.value = "Dallas",Fields!Count.value,"DallasCount",
Fields!Location.value = "Houston",Fields!Count.value,"HoustonCount"

)

Comment: Harry - Adding the switch expression resuled in this: `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:  The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox68.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for a lookup function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset`

Comment: Is the location a finite / fixed set? If it is then you could possibly do all the lookup in a single expression and concat them all.. makes sense? Worth a try I suppose. A better alternative is to do all of this in the datasource if possible. Can you not merge all the location count datasets into a single dataset?